# Laravel Accessing Attributes & Slots Within Component Classes

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a question about [Laravel - Documentation - Accessing Attributes & Slots Within Component Classes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#using-attributes-slots-wthin-component-class)

I read this section, and did some experiments. What I've found is that the closure only can return `string` but `component.view`, and what it returns would overwrite what is defined on the component view, which leads me to a question `What use case is this feature for?`

Could anyone make some examples of using this feature for me?

Anyone could help me with it will be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string matches an existing view then it will render that view and not overwrite it. You can return an existing view as follows:

```
// app/View/Components/Post.php

public function render()
{
    return function (array $data) {
        // $data['componentName'];
        // $data['attributes'];
        // $data['slot'];
    
        return 'components.post'; // /resources/views/components/post.blade.php
    };
}
```

```
// views/components/post.blade.php

<div class="item">
    <div class="title">
        New Post
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content post...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example:**

```
// component class

class Link extends Component
{
    public $path = "";
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->path = request()->path();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return function (array $data) {
            if(isset($data['attributes']['href'])) {

                $data['attributes']["link"] = $data['attributes']['href'];

                if ($data['attributes']['href'] == "/".$this->path) {
                    $data['attributes']['active'] = $data['attributes']['class']." link-active-class";
                } else {
                    $data['attributes']['active'] = $data['attributes']['class'];
                }
            }
            
            return 'components.commons.link';
        };
    }
}
```

```html
// component view 

<a href="{{ $attributes['link'] }}" class="{{ $attributes['active'] }}">
    {{ $slot }}
</a>
```

**Usage:**

```html
<x-commons.link href="/module/news" class="primary-action">
    <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> News
</x-commons.link>
```